# Mathematical induction proving f is not one to one using n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, pigeonhole-principle

I am unsure about how to go about this proof which is supposed to prove the pigeonhole principle using mathematical induction on n by proving f is not one-to-one.

"For every n≥1, every function f: A→{1,2, . . . , n}where|A|> n,f is not one-to-one."

Comment: The pigeonhole principle is a method of proving statements yea? I wouldn't say that this question is proving that the pigeon hole principle works, it's like trying to say that you can prove why a proof by contradiction works, its trivial. If you are just trying to prove the statement, you can use the pigeonhole principle to prove it.

Comment: @JeremyBaziw I disagree, this *is* a proof of the pigeon hole principal.  Th PHP stats that if $f: X\to Y$ and $|X| > |Y|$ then $f$ isnt injective.  This proves it via induction for finite sets.

Comment: Hmm, I think you *do* have to do induction.  How to I know I can't be more that 7 pigeons into 7 holes?  I mean it's obvious, but I think we *do* have to prove it, and I *do* think induction is the best. i.e.  If we put one pigeon in one hole we will have more than six pigeons left and six holes left.  How do we know *that* is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Okay... then...

Base case:

Every function $f: A \to \{1\}$ where $|A| > 1$ is not one to one.

Pf: Since $|A| > 1$ then $|A|\ge 2$ so there exist $a,b \in A$ so that $a \ne b$.

But $f(a) = 1; f(b) = 1$.  So $f$ is not one to one.

Induction step:

If every function $f: A \to \{1..... k\}$ where $|A| > k$ is not one to one, then every function $g: B\ to \{1....k+1\}$ where $|B| > k+1$ isnt one-to one.

Hint:  If $g: B \to \{1......k+1\}$ is one to one, and for $a\in B$ then if $g(a) = j$ then for all $b \in B$ so that $g(b) \ne j$.

So let $h: B\setminus\{a\} \to \{1..... k+1\}\setminus\{j\}$ where $h(b) = g(b)$ for all $b \in  B\setminus\{a\}$ is well defined.

Questions:  Is $h$ one to one?  (Hint: the answer is yes.)  Is it *possible* for $h$ to be one to one? (Hint: the answer is no.)

Hint 4:  $\{1..... k+1\}\setminus\{j\}$ is isomorphic to $\{1..... k\}$. And $|B\setminus\{a\}| = |B| -1 > k+1 -1 = k$.